# Latest Value from the column level to specific code

Tags: excel-formula

[image][image]

Can anyone pls help me to get the latest/running value for A & B....

```
NAME    FSales  ESales
A        100      500
A        50       170
B        100      300
B        130      200
A         70      230
B         50      450
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
Output  FSales  ESales
A         70    230
B         50    450
```

Comment: Smells like a homework. Have you tried anything? Please explain what you've attempted so far so that we can help you learn better. Also, please try not to put any external link here. If you need in image you can just post the image altogether in your post.

Answer (score 0):

As given in the image below, enter the formula in cell `B12` and drag to right and then down.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$7=$A12),B$2:B$7)
```

[image]